# Execute stored procedure with PetaPoco

Tags: stored-procedures, petapoco

I have a stored procedure which returns back a table value.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [GetPermitPendingApproval] 
    @permitYear int = NULL, 
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT [p].[ID]
          ,[p].[PermitNumber] 
          ,[p].[PermitTypeID]
          ,[p].[ApplicationDate]
          ,[u].[FirstName]
          ,[u].[MI]
          ,[u].[LastName]
          ,[u].[Suffix]
          ,[u].[ProfessionalTitle]
          ,[u].[WorksFor] 
      FROM [SciCollUser] u 
            INNER JOIN UserPermit up ON up.[UserID] = u.[ID] 
            INNER JOIN Permit p ON p.[ID] = [up].[PermitID] 
     WHERE (@permitYear IS NULL OR p.PermitYear = @permitYear) 
    ORDER BY [p].[ApplicationDate] ASC;
END
```

I am not sure whether we have such a way to use PetaPoco to execute a stored procedure and get a returned data as a table? Please help!

As normally I can execute a stored procedure with the follow script but it is not the way I want.

```
db.Execute("EXEC GetPermitPendingApproval @permitYear=2013");
```

Answer (score 32):

You need to put a semicolon before EXEC.

```
var result = db.Fetch<dynamic>(";EXEC GetPermitPendingApproval @@permitYear = @0", 2013);
```

Comment: can you explain why the semi colon is needed? Is this due to some internal implementation of something within PetaPoco?

Comment: @rdans  Yes it is a work around ";" allows you to end the 1st statement to start another. In other words, this ignores the 1st statement inserted by petapoco making it unused.

Comment: this horrible workaround still works like a charm in 2023, thanks

Answer (score 18):

Answer is probably late, but I hope, that it will be useful for future generations. You should turn EnableAutoSelect option to false on PetaPoco database object    `db.EnableAutoSelect = false;`
Otherwise  it will keep adding `SELECT NULL FROM [Object]` to you sql statement.

It's good, that it's possible to debug PetaPoco sources.I've found this option only because of debugging!

Answer (score 9):

You get `List<T>` where T is a POCO type with the properties you want to map or a `Dynamic`

So the actual syntax is:

```
var result = db.Fetch<dynamic>(";EXEC GetPermitPendingApproval @0", 2013);
```

or

```
var result = db.Fetch<dynamic>(";EXEC GetPermitPendingApproval @permitYear",
                                                       new {permitYear = 2013});
```

Comment: It does not work and here is an error:
Invalid object name '[Object]' from this query string
"SELECT NULL FROM [Object] EXEC GetPermitPendingApproval"

Answer (score 6):

As of v6.0.344-beta, PetaPoco now supports stored procs natively, so you can do:

```
var result = db.FetchProc<MyClass>("GetPermitPendingApproval", new { permitYear = 2013 });
```